# Flask-Security, implement SECURITY_TRACKABLE feature in Blueprint

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm using the `SECURITY_TRACKABLE` feature for Flask-Security, and in my custom API login request handler I am trying to make sure to commit the datastore changes, as required by the [flask-security documentation on `login_user()`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#flask_security.utils.login_user).

My login code is inside a blueprint:

```
from modules.auth.models import User
from flask import Blueprint, request, abort
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_security import login_required
from flask_security.utils import verify_password, login_user, logout_user 

app = Blueprint(__name__, __name__)
api = Api(app)

class LogResource(Resource):
    """
    Manages user login and logout
    """

    def post(self):
        user = User.query.filter_by(
            email = request.form['email']
        ).first()
        if not user:
            abort(401, "Wrong credentials.")

        if verify_password(request.form['password'], user.password):
            login_user(user)
            app.security.datastore.commit()
            return "Logged in"
        else:
            abort(401, description="Wrong credentials.")
```

But when the user logs in I got the error: `AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'security'`, because I'm inside a blueprint and not the app. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are referencing `app` here, but the exception says it is a blueprint. How is `app` defined in your code here?

Comment: Or put differently, can you show a *full traceback* that shows what line the exception is thrown on?

Comment: Your link to Flask-Security points to the *Utils* section of the API documentation. That's not really a helpful link, as there is nothing there about your feature.

Comment: `app` is defined inside app.py and i don't know how to access it

Comment: The first element of the Utils section describes how to use the tracking feature with the login function but it's not very clear

Comment: All you need to do is enable the feature, using `SECURITY_TRACKABLE=True`, and provided your user model [supports the required extra fields](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/models.html#trackable) you are all set. You don't need to provide a login route yourself, that's taken care of for you.

Comment: If you have a different user-login route too, then yes, you need to call `security.datastore.commit()` on the Flask-Security instance. Your error is due to `app` not being what you think it is, not because your route is in a blueprint.

Comment: You need to debug why `app` is a blueprint object and not the module you think it is. Perhaps you used a `from app import *` line at the top, for example. You didn't share that here so we can't correct that error.

Comment: I already did the configuration stated in the documentation and i didn't import nothing from app

Comment: You confused me with *`app` is defined inside app.py and i don't know how to access it*. You haven't actually shown where you create the `Security()` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Security()` object is never a direct attribute of the Flask application object. Your error here is that `app` is a `Blueprint` object, which is confusing matters more. You usually should *not* use `app` for a blueprint object anyway.

You can *import* the  object from the module where you create the `Security(...)` instance in the first place, or you can access it via the Flask `extensions` mapping via the [`current_app` reference](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.current_app):

```
from flask import current_app

security = current_app.extensions['security']  # or reference .datastore, etc.
```

Next, you generally want to commit the access *after the response is complete*, as this helps produce a faster result for the end user and lets you record response status too. Use the [`after_this_request()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.after_this_request) to run the commit after the response:

```
from flask import current_app, after_this_request

def flask_security_datastore_commit(response=None):
    datastore = current_app.extensions['security'].datastore
    datastore.commit()
    return response
```

and in your view use:

```
if verify_password(request.form['password'], user.password):
    login_user(user)
    after_this_request(flask_security_datastore_commit)
    return "Logged in"
```

Comment: I think this is the solution but after testing i got another error `AttributeError: '_SecurityState' object has no attribute 'commit'`

Comment: @andrea56: mea culpa, not sure why the `.datastore` reference that should have been there was omitted.